# Ros SSH not working

Tags: ros-melodic, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have followed Ros SSH tutorial and is working perfectly.

However, I have change both 'talker' and 'listener' files into a launch file receptively.

The talker.launch is in the client and the listener.launch is at the server.
In the server I have launch an empty world gazebo as well.

When I launch the following in sequence, the talker.launch does transmit data over to the server:

1. roscore on the server
2. Set rosclient to the rosserver
3. launch talker.launch on client
4. launch empty world gazebo
5. launch listener.launch

However when I change the sequence by launching gazebo 1st. The talker.launch does not transmit data over. "Topic is there but inside is empty". The following is the sequence.

1. roscore on server
2. Set rosclient to rosserver
3. launch empty world gazebo
4. launch talker.launch on client
5. launch listener.launch
6. Did not work so I tried rostopic echo/"Talker_topic"
   output: no message receive and simulated time active.

May I know is this an SSH bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364902/ros-ssh-not-working/) by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2020-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:

Seems like changing

rate.sleep()
to
time.sleep()

did the trick. I still don't know why tho.

---

Originally posted by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) with karma: 98 on 2020-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0